# Android Studio Cant connect to sql server from my app when connected to mobile data

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, mobile-application

I've created an app to display my sql server data on the phone, I'm connecting to the server using my public ip, when im connected to any wifi, it works, no problems, but when i try to connect using my mobile data it appears this exception "java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: failed to connect to "my public ip" (port 1433) from /:: (port 39914): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)"
this is the code im using:

```
try 
{
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SQL Connection Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I must admit, having your SQL Server open to the outside world, with no firewall rules is a terrible idea; your instance is most certainly going to end up suffering brute force attacks. Mobile Applications normally connect via an API. Exposing services like this to the entire outside world is *never* a good idea.

Comment: Its juts for testing, I'm learning android studio and would like to identify this error and know how to make it work to advance to the next courses

Comment: Your smartphone have internet connection when wifi is down? You can check it before get connection from DriverManager
[https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing#java](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing#java)

Comment: I add the check code from the page and it returns "Mobile connected: true"